# Plotting binary data in python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, binary

I have some data that looks like:

`data = [1,2,4,5,9]` (random pattern of increasing integers)

And I want to plot it in a binary horizontal line so that y=1 for every x value specified in `data` and zero otherwise.

I have a few different `data` arrays that I'd like to stack, similar to this style (this is CCD clocking data but the plot format looks ideal)

[image: binary plot]

I think I need to create a list of ones for my data array, but how do I specify the zero value for everything not in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the point. You can create a list with `1` in any position specified in data and `0` elsewhere. This can be done very easily with a list comprehension

```
def binary_data(data):
    return [1 if x in data else 0 for x in range(data[-1] + 1)]
```

which will act like this:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
>>> bindata = binary_data(data)
>>> bindata
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Now all you have to do is plot it... or better *step* it since it's binary data and `step()` looks way better:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, show

def binary_data(data):
    return [1 if x in data else 0 for x in range(data[-1] + 1)]

data = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
bindata = binary_data(data)
xaxis = np.arange(0, data[-1] + 1)
yaxis = np.array(bindata)
step(xaxis, yaxis)
show()
```

[image]

---

To plot multiple data arrays stacked on the same figure you could tweak `binary_data()` like this:

```
def binary_data(data, yshift=0):
    return [yshift+1 if x in data else yshift for x in range(data[-1] + 1)]
```

so now you can set `yshift` parameter to shift data arrays on the y-axis. E.g,

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
>>> bindata1 = binary_data(data)
>>> bindata1
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> bindata2 = binary_data(data, 2)
>>> bindata2
[2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Let's say you have `data1`, `data2` and `data3` to plot stacked, you'd go like:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, show

def binary_data(data, yshift=0):
    return [yshift+1 if x in data else yshift for x in range(data[-1] + 1)]

data1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
bindata1 = binary_data(data1)
x1 = np.arange(0, data1[-1] + 1)
y1 = np.array(bindata1)

data2 = [1, 4, 9]
bindata2 = binary_data(data2, 2)
x2 = np.arange(0, data2[-1] + 1)
y2 = np.array(bindata2)

data3 = [1, 2, 8, 9]
bindata3 = binary_data(data3, 4)
x3 = np.arange(0, data3[-1] + 1)
y3 = np.array(bindata3)

step(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
show()
```

that you can easily edit to make it work with an arbitrary amount of data arrays:

```
data = [ [1, 2, 4, 5, 9],
         [1, 4, 9],
         [1, 2, 8, 9] ]

for shift, d in enumerate(data):
    bindata = binary_data(d, 2 * shift)
    x = np.arange(0, d[-1] + 1)
    y = np.array(bindata)
    step(x, y)

show()
```

[image]

---

Finally if you are dealing with data arrays with different length (say `[1,2]` and `[15,16]`) and you don't like plots that vanish in the middle of the figure you can tweak `binary_data()` again to force its range to the maximum range of your data.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, show

def binary_data(data, limit, yshift=0):
    return [yshift+1 if x in data else yshift for x in range(limit)]


data = [  [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 12, 13, 14],
          [1, 4, 10, 11,  20, 21, 22],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18] ]

# find out the longest data to plot
limit = max( [ x[-1] + 1 for x in data] )
x = np.arange(0, limit)

for shift, d in enumerate(data):
    bindata = binary_data(d, limit, 2 * shift)
    y = np.array(bindata)
    step(x, y)

show()
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested, if you prefer to perform `data` to `bindata` conversion without having to define your own `binary_data()` function you could use `numpy.zeros_like()`. Just pay more attention when you stack them:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, show

data = [  [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 12, 13, 14],
          [1, 4, 10, 11,  20, 21, 22],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 17, 18] ]

# find out the longest data to plot
limit = max( [ x[-1] + 1 for x in data] )
x = np.arange(0, limit)

for shift, d in enumerate(data):
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    y[d] = 1
    # don't forget to shift
    y += 2*shift
    step(x, y)

show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array with all zeros and assign `1` for those elements in data

```
import numpy as np

data = [1,2,4,5,9]
t = np.arange(0,data[-1]+1)
x = np.zeros_like(t)
x[data] = 1
```

You might then plot it with the step function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.step(t,x, where="post")
plt.show()
```

[image]

or with `where = "pre"`, depending on how to interprete your data

[image]